# If not - than do this

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$( "#target" ).scroll(function() {

        if ( !($('#log'))  ) {
      $( "#log" ).append( "<div>Handler for .scroll() called.</div>" );
    };
});
```

I want to append #log to the body if there isn't already a #log div, but if there is do nothing.  How do I do this, my code doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest, *especially* in events like `scroll`, to cache your jQuery objects for future use: `var $log = $("#log");`, to be defined *outside* the event registration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `$('#log').length` to see how many objects are found.

In your case it might be

```
if (!$('#log').length) {
    // ...
}
```

Your solution does not work because `!$('#log')` expression is always `false`, because any object in JS (and `$()` function always returns an object, even if nothing was found) is always truthy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#log" ).append( "<div>Handler for .scroll() called.</div>" );
```

Instead of that try using this :

```
$("#log").appendTo('body');
```